# how to load large files into memory

Tags: linux, grub

I'm working on a live linux distro but when I compile the programs, the init file has 1.1G size and when I try to boot it, grub says `Error 28: Selected item cannot fit into memory`.

How does other large size distros load their programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, other distros *don't* put everything in the initrd. They only have a very small initrd which mounts the actual rootfs from another image (could be ext4, but more commonly a .squashfs), in exactly the same way that "installed" systems use a initrd to mount the rootfs.

This way, the large rootfs is handled by the Linux kernel – not by GRUB – so it is not subject to the limitations of GRUB's environment, and can be paged in on-demand (Linux doesn't need to load the whole 1.1GB into memory)